# Why is having a NotImplementedException a good thing?

Tags: c#, language-design, language-features

C# has made a language feature of the `NotImplementedException`. It's added to a lot of auto-generated code, such as event handler stubs:

```
// Auto-generated
private void TextBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

What makes this exception

- useful?
- a good language feature?

It seems to me that the only person who *should* ever see that exception thrown is the developer of a piece of software - but that's what issue and TODO tracking systems are for.

Comment: It's only a good thing as far as its a very visible reminder that something isn't done. Far too often however, it's used to avoid fully implementing an interface, which should never be done because it breaks Liskov's substitution principle.

Comment: @RubberDuck That question seems to be more about if it should be *used*; I'm wondering why the designers added it in the first place.

Comment: Short of Eric Lippert showing up, I don't think anyone here can rightfully answer that question @ArtOfCode. (Not the downvoter btw. It's a good question, just looks like a dupe to me.)

Comment: How is it a language feature? The behavior of an IDE is not a language feature.

Comment: @svick The exception itself is what I'm referring to. The auto-generated thing was there as an example.

Comment: @ArtOfCode That's still not a language feature, the Base Class Library is technically not part of the language.

Comment: As Brian Kernighan once said (in a lecture I attended) -- "what runs, the code or the comments?"

Comment: Heh. @RubberDuck your wish came true ^

Comment: I believe Eric Lippert kibozes Stack Overflow, showing up wherever his name is mentioned. And then there's people like me, who regularly check *his* [activity feed](https://stackexchange.com/users/32093/eric-lippert?tab=activity) to see what wisdom he's bestowed lately…

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It allows the code to compile for your method stub (regardless of the method's return type), while you get around to putting in an implementation.

It also reminds you to put in the implementation, because it will throw the first time you try to MouseDown on that textbox.  A thrown exception that says "This method is not implemented" is much better than clicking a textbox and wondering why nothing happens.

Answer (score 7):

There is an additional case which wasn't mentioned in the previous answers: mocks for unit tests.

A mock can need to implement only a small part of an interface, but to compile, it should declare all of them. The not implemented exception makes then a very clear difference between methods which are actually required by the test, but return nothing or a dummy value, and methods which aren't needed during the test.

Comment: That would be `NotSupportedException`, not `NotImplementedException`. I note that `NotSupportedException` is also used by many BCL types like `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` and various `Stream` subclasses when it was commonplace (but not necessarily a good idea) for types to only partially implement an interface - this was before the advent of `IReadOnlyList<T>`, I note).

Comment: @Dai I disagree. `NotSupportedException` is used when implementing a method is optional and there is an explicit choice not to. `NotImplementedException` is used prior to any implementation decisions. With mocks, the programmer doesn't choose to *not* implement each unimplemented method. They haven't thought about it, and won't think about it.

Comment: @ILMTitan That's not my opinion though - [Microsoft's own documentation for `NotImplementedException`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.notimplementedexception?view=netcore-3.1) says "a NotImplementedException exception should be synonymous with 'still in development.'" - there's no mention in the article suggesting it _should_ be used for mocks and the "other exception types" section name-drops `NotSupportedException`.